# How can obfuscate Sqlite Database in android

Tags: android, android-proguard, android-database

I create **External database** with **SQLite Expert Professional** IDE and i insert many data into this `database` and i what add this `database` in my Android Project. but i want **obfuscate** this database.

I want when other developers decompile my projects, **not see** my data in database!

how can it?

Comment: google sqlcipher

Comment: @petey, can you help me more? i am amateur. please